# Is there an option for splitting cells in Material UI table

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to split a cell in `Material UI` table :
`import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table'`
Of course i know i always have the option of creating a component which does this and instead of a text, putting this component inside a cell, but since this feature is so widely used in tables i thought maybe there is an option i don't know about ?, which is why i decided to ask a question here
Just to clarify, this is why i mean by splitting a cell:
[image]

As you can see each cell has two values which are separated using a line.
Is there a setting, option or recommended way to achieve this in `Material UI table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific feature to do this, but you can very easily achieve this by using a [<Divider />](https://material-ui.com/components/dividers/) inside the cell, like this:

```
<TableCell>
  9703
  <Divider />
  (16.23) 0.54
</TableCell>
```

Comment: Nice, i didn't know about the `Divider`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      ...
      divider: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
      }
    })); 




  <TableCell align="center" >
      153
      <Divider className={classes.divider} />
      186
    </TableCell>
```